# Bullet fired at a series of partitions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision, projectile

Imagine a bullet fired at a series of partitions stacked one after the other. Given that the bullet looses half its velocity in crossing each partition, velocity of the same is a geometric progression(GP) with $a= v_0$ and $r=0.5$.

The question is, how many partitions is it supposed to successfully cross, or at what partition would the bullet be stopped?

Comment: There's something missing from the question. What's the minimum velocity needed to break through a single partition?

Comment: Are you trying to recreate [Zeno's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno's_paradoxes)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer is $\infty$/"never", since the velocity after the $i^{\rm{th}}$ partition is $v_i=ar^{i-1}$ by normal GP formulae; and an exponential can only approach zero. But you probably knew that.

Maybe there's a mistake in the question?

Comment: Yup, that's why I asked it. I distinctly remember it having a specific answer, and probably had something to do with losing Kinetic energy at each collision.

Comment: Does this make any sense? the amount of kinetic energy lost at each collision is 3/4 of the energy before the collision, and the total energy to be lost is one unit, and hence the bullet with stop at the second partition. I'd have to recheck the calculations however.

Comment: @Vaibhav No, you'll get an infinite series there as well. The common ratio will be $\frac34$ instead. Are you sure that the fraction $\frac12$ was of the velocity before hitting the plate or of the initial velocity? In the latter case the problem is trivial, answer is 2 (you get an AP, not a GP)

Comment: It is an infinite series, but it will take a finite time.

Comment: @Bernhard: Uhh, how? Its getting slower, not faster. If it gets slower, it will take more and more time to reach the next barrier. So the time taken will be $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \frac{d}{v}=\sum \frac{d\times \Large{2^i}}{v_0}=\infty$

Comment: Hmm, the question is not very clear, but I thought of the limit of $d$ very thin and very closely packed.

Comment: @Bernhard: Then its still not computable (try taking a limit, you still get $\infty$). Unless $d$ is expressed in terms of $i$.

Comment: I was thinking in an analogy of a bouncing ball which is losing momemtum every bounce, it takes a finite time for it to come to halt. Indeed, then you have $d$ expressed in $i$. This question is less complicated.